# How to find and implement all the abstract methods in PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm

Is there a smart way to find and implement all the abstract methods in PyCharm Community Edition?

I've found there's a "Implement methods (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>)", but it's always been disabled.

For example:

```
class Base():
  @abstractmethod
  def abstract1(self):
     raise NotImplementedError

  @abstractmethod
  def abstract2(self):
     raise NotImplementedError

  def method1(self):
    print("ok")
```

If I write a sub class, is there a smart way to implement `abstract1` and `abstract2` in my sub class, but not `method1`?

Because I found use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> will need to read the source before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definition of subclass would be highlighted as below.

[image]

Use `Alt+Enter` on class name to call intention that will suggest methods to implement.

[image]

There is an issue for `Implement Methods..` action, please vote for [it](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-22215).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this helped me a lot.